# CSS: Change Button appearance on Hover

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my web page with class "btnNewL1" . my CSS class is as below

```
.btnNewL1
{

background: url(../images/btnbgnew.png);
border:1px solid #818181;
padding-left:3px;
padding-right:3px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

When user place the mouse over the button,i want to chnage the appearance like change of bg image and chnage of border color etc... . I want to do this will CSS itself. and it should be be supported by IE6 IE 7 ,Firefox

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately **:hover pseudo selector is not supported by IE6** on any other element than `<a>`.

If you wish to implement :hover on IE6, you can:

**a)** If possible, change your  `<input
    class="btnNewL1" type="button"
    value="click me!" />`  to  `<a 
    class="btnNewL1" href="#">click
    me!</a>`. You will need to add display:block, and few other CSS rules. This will simply 'simulate' button using `<a>` tag. This is not perfect solution because sometimes you must use proper `<input>` (i.e. when using asp.net controls).

**b)** Use javascript to make workaround, example in jQuery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.btnNewL1").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('buttonSelected');
    }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('buttonSelected');
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="click me!" class="btnNewL1" />
```

**c)** Wrap your code like that:

```
<a class="acont" href="#"><input type="button" value="click me!" /></a>
```

So you will be able to use CSS:

```
.acont:hover input { background:red; }
```

This will do the job, but as far I remember this is not valid HTML (`<input>` should not be placed inside `<a>` tag)

Which one you gonna choose - up to you. Main point from this post is, again: **:hover pseudo selector can be used on IE6 only on anchor elements**

Comment: Most of the time the rollover effect isn't important enough to me to bother with an IE6 compatible solution.  But the OP did mention IE6 and I give you a +1 for addressing the issues around that.

Comment: thanks Steve. I do think the same but we should still remember about IE6 because plenty of people are using it. Oh, and btw I edited my post so now there are three solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
.btnNewL1:hover{
    background: url(../images/different.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the tw images into one and then change the background position.

[CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

[CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

Answer (score 0):

This SO question ["How to use ‘hover’ in CSS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css) might help you.

I think what you are looking for the `:hover` class.

Here is an example at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_hover.asp).

The example is for color, but I believe you can do this with other styles.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `:hover` pseudo-class. Use `.btnNewL1:hover { ... }` for your mouse-over styles.

See also the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors) for more info on pseudo-classes.