# How to change an image on click using CSS alone?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image and when the image is clicked I want to reveal another image below it. I am looking for a simple CSS only solution.

Is that possible?

Comment: no. click is an `event` and `CSS` can't help you with this. you can change the image on hover.

Comment: Do you want to reveal the image _while_ it is clicked, or toggle the image every time it is clicked?

Comment: check out [my suggested solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795397/547020), i think you'll like it.

Comment: Im not sure this 4 year old post will get ressurected. But how do you reveal when an image only on mouseover?

Comment: @Sidhartha - You could do something like `img:hover { background: url(/path-to-image/img.jpg); }` or use sprites as noted in the answer below. You can read more about hover [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css), and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use an `<a>` tag with different styles:

```
a:link    { }
a:visited { }
a:hover   { }
a:active  { }
```

I'd recommend using that in conjunction with CSS sprites: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the best way for using a CSS only solution.

Comment: this doesn't allow for toggling a state (how to change the image back on an additional click?), as `visited` will persist until the browser cache is cleaned.

Answer (score 22):

### TL;DR!

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/150/160');
    appearance: none;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/170/180');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

---

### A Pure CSS Solution

#### Abstract

A checkbox input is a native element served to implement toggle functionality, we can use that to our benefit.

Utilize the `:checked` pseudo class - attach it to a pseudo element of a checkbox (since you can't really affect the background of the `input` itself), and change its background accordingly.

#### Implementation

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content: url('images/icon.png');
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: url('images/another-icon.png');
}
```

#### Demo

Here's a [**full working demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/DwArh/) to illustrate the approach.

### Refactoring

This is a bit cumbersome, and we could make some changes to clean up unnecessary stuff; as we're not really applying a background image, but instead setting the element's `content`, we can omit the pseudo elements and set it directly on the checkbox.

Admittedly, they serve no real purpose here but to mask the native rendering of the checkbox. We could simply remove them, but that would result in a FOUC in best cases, or if we fail to fetch the image, it will simply show a huge checkbox.

Enters the `appearance` property:

> The `(-moz-)appearance` CSS property is used ... to display an element
> using a platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme.

we can override the platform-native styling by assigning `appearance: none` and bypass that glitch altogether (we would have to account for vendor prefixes, naturally, and *the prefix-free form is not supported anywhere*, at the moment). The selectors are then simplified, and the code is more robust.

#### Implementation

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    content: url('images/black.cat');
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    content: url('images/white.cat');
}
```

#### Demo

Again, a [**live demo of the refactored version is on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/2rwnz/).

### References

- [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
- [`-moz-appearance`/`-webkit-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

<del>***Note:** this only works on webkit for now, I'm trying to have it fixed for gecko engines also. Will post the updated version once I do.*</del>

***Update:** the `appearance` property is now [widely adopted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance#browser_compatibility), so the use of vendor prefixes is redundant. Horay!*

Comment: The CSS Ninja uses a similar approach for his [Futurebox](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/futurebox3). That is a lightbox in CSS. +1 for the input idea.

Comment: thanks, @feeela, and pleased to meet, CSS Ninja (wow, he has really taken this to the next level, great stuff. did you see the [bootstrap plugins](http://labs.thecssninja.com/bootleg/index.html)?).

Comment: Quite easy to make cross browser when you use a label for the input: http://jsfiddle.net/01cwd1wq/

Comment: The fact that the first part of the answer works on webkit related browsers is only a non-standard deviation. An `input` cannot have a `after` or `before` pseudo since it's not an element with a closing tag, needed to contain said pseudo element. So it's basically incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

some people have suggested the "visited", but the visited links remain in the browsers cache, so the next time your user visits the page, the link will have the second image.. i dont know it that's the desired effect you want. Anyway you coul mix JS and CSS:

```
<style>
.off{
    color:red;
}
.on{
    color:green;
}
</style>
<a href="" class="off" onclick="this.className='on';return false;">Foo</a>
```

using the onclick event, you can change (or toggle maybe?) the class name of the element. In this example i change the text color but you could also change the background image.

Good Luck

Comment: the OP has requested a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (but once clicked, it is not reversible):

HTML:

```html
<a id="test"><img src="normal-image.png"/></a>
```

CSS:

```css
a#test {
    border: 0;
}
a#test:visited img, a#test:active img {
    background-image: url(clicked-image.png);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This introduces a new paradigm to HTML/CSS, but using an `<input readonly="true">` would allow you to append an `input:focus` selector to then alter the `background-image`

This of course would require applying specific CSS to the `input` itself to override browser defaults but it does go to show that click actions can indeed be triggered without the use of Javascript.

Comment: huh? please demonstrate.

Comment: Sure... So take a look at this page: http://daleyjem.com/sandbox/css-playground.html ... Don't mind the clock, but the 4th menu item is actually an `<input/>`

Comment: interesting, though it still poses some issues, e.g. what about keyboard navigation? this won't look too hot as in some engine implementations text is highlighted on keyboard focus to an input.

Comment: True. You could also use the method used on the actual <a> tags, which is... set the a:target {} selector in css, and make sure your href (minus the hash tag) matches the id of the <a> tag.

Comment: fascinating, love the approach. +1

Comment: The url above is dead. Try this instead for an example: https://codepen.io/daleyjem/pen/PLBZXO

Answer (score 2):

You can use the different states of the link for different images [example](http://csscreator.com/node/28450)

You can also use the same image ([css sprite](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/)) which combines all the different states and then just play with the padding and position to show only the one you want to display.

Another option would be using javascript to replace the image, that would give you more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need scripting to place a `click` `Event` handler on the `Element` that does what you want.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events