# creating a button click effect - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering on how I could go about recreating a button pressed effect using JQuery.

My ideas where to use a event for mouse click to change image to pressed image and than after mouse releases, return back to original image.  What are you thoughts or ideas on ways I could accomplish this?

Comment: You can actually just use CSS for this. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/css-change-image-on-click

Comment: I know but I don't want to use <a> tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work. The code would be:

```
$("#button").mousedown(function(){
$("#img").attr("src", "img2.jpg");
})
$("#button").mouseup(function(){
$("#img").attr("src", "img1.jpg");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad to help. I would appreciate a check, both to stop other people from looking at this and help my abysmal reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Have the image listen to the click event and change the source of the image.

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src === 'something' ? 'somethingelse' : 'something' ;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks :)  I like @newbie's solution better though.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly ? something like this is the way ...

```
$('btn-img').click(function(){
   var img =  $(this).children('img'); // return object of inner img
   // your event on current img with click
}).mouseleave(function(){
   // other event on mouseleave
});
```

Html :

```
<a class="btn-img">
    <img src="yourImage.jpg" />
</a>
```