# Change image onclick and again change to previous image on clicking again - only using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I have tried following code which is onclicking an image it changes to another image and again it should switch back to previous image on clicking again. In below code the image will only stay visible while you are holding down the mouse button. I want to have it stay visible until you click again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>HTML5 form</title><link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/e/ref.ico" />
<style type="text/css">
div.nav {
height: 340px;
width: 300px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image:url("http://s24.postimg.org/6g070ei6d/logo.jpg");
}

div.nav a, div.nav a:link, div.nav a:visited {
display:block;
}

div.nav img {
border:0;
}

div.nav a:active img {
visibility:hidden;
.thumbnail:focus span
visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'></head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<a href="#">
<img src="http://s10.postimg.org/bthpk39yh/logo_red.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can't do click events with just CSS. That's where you'll need javascript or jQuery. The best you can do with CSS is :active but this only works when the mouse is held down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .checkbox { display: none; }
        .label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: url(http://www.letsgomobile.org/images/reviews/0102/samsung-camera-phone-test-photos.jpg);
        }
        .checkbox:checked + .label {
            background: url(http://www.letsgomobile.org/images/reviews/0102/samsung-camera-phone-test-pictures.jpg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checked">
    <label class="label" for="checked"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform without using checkbox ? why because is I am going to use this in email. The outlook doesn't support form elements like checkboxes. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It could be done with a checkbox. Found it here [How to change an image on click using CSS alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone)

```
<input class="native-hidden" type="checkbox" />

input[type="checkbox"] {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/200/150');
}
.native-hidden {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/2rwnz/

Comment: Stone the crows! Why would someone use something like this =) But nice to know...

Comment: @jotaen I would use JS, but I'm sure Anand has his reasons for not using it.