# Changes set of images on click - Fotorama

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fotorama

Is there a way to change the images that are in Fotorama when I click in a div?

For example, I have two divs, one called #NYPhotos and the other called #WAPhotos. When I click on div #NYPhotos, Fotorama appears below it, showing the photos I took in New York. After that, when I click on #WAPhotos, the images in fotorama are swapped to the photos of Washington.

I was able to make Fotorama appear with the NY photos, but had no luck trying to swap the images... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend reading the answer to this question which should help: [How to change an image on click using CSS alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone)

If you don't want to read that then basically the main idea is:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:before {
     content: url('images/icon.png');
     display: block;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
content: url('images/another-icon.png');
}
```

Just make each section a div using CSS. Hope this helped!