# By click on an icon it should change to another icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i click an icon the icon have to change to another icon

befor clicking if it is "cat" after click that it should change to "rat"

Mostly with out using jquery.

Comment: have you made any attempt at solving this problem?.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (jQuery code):

```
$(function() {
 $('.yourIconClass').click(function(){
   $("#yourIconId").attr('src',"img/picture1.jpg");
   return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this isn't coders golf, but I've tried a quick and dirty solution:

```
<img id="catrat" src="cat.jpg" onclick="javascript:changeImage()">

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById("catrat").src = "rat.jpg" 
    }
</script>
```

Hope that helps, but I think searching would have brought up a thousand websites with the same solution.

Comment: with out using jquery

Comment: Huh? This isn't jquery, just plain JavaScript... The answer above used jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you realy should try solving your problems before asking such simpe stuff.

check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

mini example without real code

you need a script with a function

you need a div with a id (place first image here)

when image is clicked call the function() in your script

use the link above to figure out the getelementbydid ... innerHTML which must be placed in your function.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/DwArh/129/)**

using checkbox

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content: url('http://www.bernardbrogue.com/images/fb24_24.png');
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: url('http://isleofcapricasinos.com/uploadedImages/z-Asset_Library/Miscellaneous/Google-Plus-Logo-24x24.png?n=1533');
}
```

from : [How to change an image on click using CSS alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone)