# Showing hidden content via css

Tags: css

So, to better explain, I am attaching a simple image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

There is a button, and three contents (two visible and one hidden located in between as shown above).

When the button is clicked, I want to show the hidden content which is located in between to contents.

Is it possible to achieve this with CSS alone?

For example, I can have the hidden content with `display:none;` then force it visible somehow?

I am not sure what the most efficient way to achieve this.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at my answer again . I added JQuery for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve this using CSS only then there is a way using check boxes or Radio buttons instead of HMTL button tag.

here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/yt76h26n/

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"/>
<div class="box one">1</div>
<div class="box two">2</div>
<div class="box three">3</div>

.box{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background: gray;
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.two{
    display:none;
}

.check:checked ~ .two {
    display:block
}
```

And you can style checkbox or Radio button as per your convenience.

Comment: Thank you Nilesh. I didn't think of radio button option. I will keep that in mind. Also, does `checked ~ .two` specify `.two` only? I never used `checked ~` before. Learning something new =)

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. `.two` is to target div which we want to show and hide.  `:checked` selector will work when checbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
.visible_content:hover > .hidden_content {display:block;}
```

when you hover on `.visible_content` , `.hidden_content` will be shown.

but with click , I don't think that there be any way to do this via css.

but in jquery , it is simple:

```
$(".visible_content").click(function(){
    $(".hidden_content").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! =) I will give it a try. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Do it purely in css solution here:
[How to change an image on click using CSS alone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813699/how-to-change-an-image-on-click-using-css-alone)

However, with jquery it can easily be done in 3 seconds with only a couple of lines if you're not opposed to it as shown below!

```
$("#buttonsid button").click(function(){
    $("#idofhiddencontent").toggle();
});
```

Comment: I will totally give this a try! =) Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you think is better in between javascript vs css in terms of speed and efficiency?

Comment: I don't think you'll notice a difference on a small application in terms of speed however to keep a "separation of concerns" I recommend keeping behaviors with javascript as much as possible.  Especially if you plan to add a lot of user interaction.

Comment: Okay, I was testing various solutions given in this question. I will use javascript as much as possible =) Thanks Brian

Comment: No problem.  If you're looking to do a lot of animating I'd check out:https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 45px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.block-hidden{
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    color: #f00;
}

.btn:focus ~ .block-hidden{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Button Click</a>

<div class="block">Block</div>
<div class="block block-hidden">Block Hidden</div>
<div class="block">Block</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy! =) I will implement this and compare it with javascript. Really appreciate it