# Ways to improve redundant jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery snip to make a up / down slide effect when hovering. I made it with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/1/

Now i have a navigation like that:

```
<nav id="menu" class="nav">                 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="slide default">
                            <span>About</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide onhover">
                            <span>About</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="slide default">
                            <span>Photography</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide onhover">
                            <span>Photography</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="slide default">
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide onhover">
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="slide default">
                            <span>Webdesign</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide onhover">
                            <span>Webdesign</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="slide default">
                            <span>Linkbase</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slide onhover">
                            <span>Linkbase</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

To add the effect from the fiddle, i created the jQuery part like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            var height = $(".nav ul li").height();

            $('li:nth-child(5n+1)').mouseover(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+1) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: 0    
                }, height);                        
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+1) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: height 
                }, height)    
            });
            $('li:nth-child(5n+2)').mouseover(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+2) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: 0    
                }, height);                        
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+2) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: height 
                }, height)    
            });
            $('li:nth-child(5n+2)').mouseover(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+2) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: 0    
                }, height);                        
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+2) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: height 
                }, height)    
            });
            $('li:nth-child(5n+2)').mouseover(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+2) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: 0    
                }, height);                        
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+1) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: height 
                }, height)    
            });
            $('li:nth-child(5n+1)').mouseover(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+1) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: 0    
                }, height);                        
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $('li:nth-child(5n+1) .default').stop().animate({
                    height: height 
                }, height)    
            });

        });
```

It works fine. But the jQuery code is redundant and long. But I have no idea to improve that to make it slimmer.

The solution should be compatible with older browser, so it should be jQuery for the transition...

Have you some ideas?

Comment: CSS has a `:hover` pseudo selector. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css

Comment: In addition, you can use `transitions` in CSS3. Is there a reason you need to use jQuery for this when you can just use pure CSS?

Comment: @JaredEitnier That would be backwards-compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: He didn't specify what browsers he cares about. Maybe it's not an issue.

Comment: @JaredEitnier CSS3 is certainly wonderful, but for most of us out here in the web development world, backwards compatibility tends to override our desire to opt for pure CSS3 or HTML5 implementations of things.  Even with polyfills and shims, cutting-edge CSS properties still present major issues on browsers like IE8.  Most of my sites use jQuery for animation effects, and then I just add CSS3 features throughout the site as "icing on the cake" for those using modern and mobile browsers.

Comment: I'm not new to the idea guys, just wanting to get some additional info. If he is developing an internal app for a company that strictly uses firefox and chrome like we do at my company than why would he waste the time?

Comment: Well, he is actually not wasting time since he clearly said it's working. It would be a waste of time changing to CSS3 actually. He just asked to improve his code, wich is in my opinion a good way of learning jQuery.

Comment: @JaredEitnier: I like CSS3, but my site should displayed also on older browser correctly. I specified my question.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Uhm. Yes i know. But a only css solution without css3 isn't possible, right? So it should be backwards-compatibility

Comment: @user2413035 which is why I left a comment and not an answer :) using `:hover` which is not CSS3 but CSS1 iirc (works in IE6 for sure), would spare you all the duplicate divs for sure.

Comment: @j08691: Oh nice, i don't know there is a SO-Part like that. I'm sorry. So i ask there. But i can't close the question here....

Comment: You should also cache your selectors. Otherwise, you are querying the DOM everytime.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: But it is possible with my transition animation?

Comment: @Chris Till: What? Again for a hobby programmer :)

Comment: He means store the DOM elements to a variable and call the variable instead of the DOM each time.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks @JaredEitnier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to fully understand your code (because of all those nth-child), but I think it can be shorter like that :

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.default').stop().animate({
        height: height    
    }, height);                  
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.default').stop().animate({
        height: 0    
    }, height);
})
```

Using `hover` reduce the number of event to 1. The first first function is like mouse enter and the second is mouse out.

You can use `this` to know wich element is hovered.

Comment: Oh cool! I don't know that `this` gives you the hovered element back. Just switch the 0 and height in the two methods, and then it works well :) and for your information: nth-child is a special css selector... :)

Comment: Oh I know what it is, but there was so much `nth-child`, I was so lost! I was wondering if you knew about `this` because I couldn't understand why using `nth-child` so much ahah! By the way, for further reference, instead of using `nth-child` in jquery, use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: Cool thank you :) Nice weekend!