# Hover div change background properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background image, but what I wanted is that when I hover that div, the background would turn with a filter transparent white (like 50% transparency), so we could see  both the background and the image I have inside the div. I didn't want that this filter to affect the image inside it, only the background.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 back-div">
    <img src="imgs/logo.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .back-div{
    background-image: url("../imgs/imgbg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there any js framework to do this with some animations also?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use 'hover' in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css)

Comment: I think you can do this in CSS but if you want jQuery is also an option (among the other frameworks as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with some simple jQuery (allowing you to reuse it on multiple elements of similar structure). *I gave you jQuery because you asked form animation as well as the hover opacity effect and jQuery alleviates the various browser incompatibilities with css animations.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/wC9F3/)**

New JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.back-div').hover(function(){
        $('.back-div img').animate({opacity: 0.5},1000);
    }, function(){
        $('.back-div img').animate({opacity: 1},1000);
    });
});
```

New CSS:

```
.back-div img {  
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some jQuery to modify the div.

```
 $(".back-div").css({ 'background': 'whatever'});
```

You can out it inside a function and you can play with it. It will give you a more personalized functionality.

If not, try play with this too (in CSS):

```
opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pretend the background by another internal div

```
<div class="your-cont">
    <div class="fake-bg"></div>
    <img src="imgs/logo.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.your-cont {
     position:relative;
}
.your-cont:hover .fake-bg {
     opacity:0.5;
}
.fake-bg {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```