# Need help getting a hyperlink in an h2 to change color on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an h2 in a div, and the h2 itself is a link. The link is displayed in one color already (code example below)

```
       <div>
        <h2 class="className">
            <a href="#" style="color: #006BA6;">Title</a></h2>
       </div> 

    .className
    {
        color: #006BA6;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 14px;
    }
```

What I need to do is make it so when I hover over the h2 link "Title" the color will change to another color. I have searched everywhere and have yet to find a successful way to do this.

I have tried something like this:

```
h1, h2, h3{
    a{
         color:#d99a30 !important;
         &:hover{ color:#37404e !important;}
      }
}
```

And a handful of other options, including a new class for the h2 and a new class for the link and nothing is working. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I want to take one quick second and apologize for potentially asking a duplicate question. It was not my intention to waste anybody's time by not being thorough enough in my searching. I am still very, ***very*** new to CSS and kind of figuring things out as I go. A lot of the code I am working with is pre-existing, so I am worried about small kinds of changes making large changes throughout the entire site. Thank you all for your help, suggestions, and links to tutorials/documentation. I will be sure to be more thorough in the future before asking a question.

Comment: Are you using less or sass or some sort of CSS preprocessor? If so please update the tags on your question.

Comment: Hey Conrad, welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't mean to be rude, but looking at your CSS it seems you are lacking some very basic knowledge. Have you actually read through some tutorials and/or documentation before coming here? Also, please take a quick look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 'hover' in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css)

Comment: Hey @domdom I am very, very new to CSS. My company basically threw me in and said "Hey, do this." I have spent a handful of hours looking through documentation because it was a change for one specific link and whether I am just bad at searching or wasn't using the right terms, I couldn't find what I was looking for. The question you linked above didn't even show up.

Thank you for your comments as well as the questions you posted. I will be sure to look at them!

Comment: That makes sense. I recommend [MDN's CSS tutorial area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS) for some basics, but there are plenty of other CSS tutorials out there, of course.

Comment: Conrad, you should mark one of the provided answers as *accepted* (green tick mark), so that your question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
    .className
    {
        color: #006BA6; /*General color for text in this class*/
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 14px;
    }
    
    .className a{
        color: red; /*Color for hyperlinks in this class*/
    
    }
    
    .className a:hover{ /*:hover selector is self-explanatory :)*/
        color: green;
    }
```

```html
     <div>
        <h2 class="className">
            <a href="#">Title</a></h2>
       </div>
```

Additional notes:

- don't use "!important" unless You now what are You doing
- go to https://www.w3schools.com/css/ and improve Your knowledge about basics of CSS

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to guide a learner to a resource like the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) instead of w3schools, because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Answer (score 0):

Please brush up on your basic HTML/CSS knowledge and read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
For the time being, check this out:

```css
h2 a {
  color: #006BA6;
}

h2:hover a {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    <a href="#">Title</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Note that I removed the inline-styling of the `a` element, as inline styling always has priority over that coming from a `style` section or external stylesheet. Plus, it is considered bad practice.

Also note that `h2 a:hover` would work just as well. The difference is that the one I chose will change the color of your `a` when you hover anywhere over the `h2`, while the latter will only trigger when you actually hover the `a` within a `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not have an own class for your link? Just remove the style attribute in the link, so your html looks like this:

```
<div>
  <h2 class="className">
    <a href="#" class="link">Title</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

And then add the following style sheet:

```
.className
{
    color: #006BA6;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 14px;
}

.link
{
    color: #006BA6;
}

.link:hover
{
    color: #37404e;
}
```

So your class name sets the color of the Title, but the color of the link will be overwritten by the link, and the link has an own hover, which will override the color from the normal link.