# Font change onmouseover onmouseout

Tags: javascript, css

what would be the code for this: Insert a link. When mouse is over, the link font turns bold and underlined, when mouse is out, it comes back to the initial form

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It is expected that you do a little research before you post a question and most basic html tutorials will answer what you are trying to do

Comment: Research effort / Google-Fu: -1/10

Comment: Also most likely a duplicate. For example, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Only using CSS:

```
a:hover {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: me neither... :P, maybe they want people to research more before asking basic questions ..

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions that are off topic for the site, it's not useful for the OP to learn how to ask a good question and will lead them to being this lazy in future, thus filling the site with rubbish questions

Answer (score 0):

you can change the font on `hover` whic will get back to its original font when mouseout

```
a:hover{
    font-weight:600;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000;
}
```