# How to animate containers using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container that holds images of work. How do I use JS to bring up a button and some extra info on the image when I hover over it.

I tried using CSS and the hover tag but it would apply the effect I needed below the image, Not on top of it. The page is HTML, with CSS and the only JS code will be for this effect. The site is for my portfolio so each image is different but the class is all the same. The code below is what the original code is without the effect. If you could show me how to correctly do this I would really appreciate it, thanks.

I don't have the code I tried using before as I tried that many it felt pointless. I'll edit the question when I attempt another solution and post either the failed attempt or the successful attempt.

Here is a `<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/mno2fjek/">JSFiddle </a>` link

Comment: You will most likely see your question get downvoted unless you put a little more time into providing an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover - read about the css :hover selector. Play around with it till you understand what your HTML and CSS needs to be for your desired goal. Then provide a working example and explain what you are struggling with.

Comment: I erased the code when it didn't fit into the Div correctly, spent a couple hours playing around with it so I can't provide the exact code. I'll continue to look for another way around it and if it fails I will post the failed attempt to see what people suggest.

Comment: You will hear people on Stack Overflow say things like "SO is not a code writing service." What they mean by that is your question has to be pointed and specific. When I read your question I get the sense there are some fundamentals missing in your understanding. Please do not be discouraged by this comment. I want to help you. If you put together a jsfiddle or codepen or a SO snippet and show what you have tried I will help you understand how to fix it. But I HAVE to see that you tried.

Comment: Specifically "I tried using CSS and the hover tag but it would apply the effect I needed below the image" this comment leads me to believe you need to better understand how to structure your HTML and what CSS to apply to what elements. Lets start there and build from that understanding.

Comment: I also can't help but feel this is probably a question that has been asked many times before... like when I google "How to use :hover" I get the first link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css

Comment: I was trying to use JS because it would just be a simple script I could rerun on each container when needed. Yes, you are correct about me not knowing how to structure questions on this platform, first time using it. I am currently working on an alternative way now, I will keep you updated and post is using JSfiddle, thanks tho, you seem helpful and willing.

Comment: @Kinetic I would recommend you utilize the snippet feature in your post rather than attempting to bypass the restrictions on linking to external fiddles if you don't have any code in your post. [Here is some information on the topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358212/how-do-i-include-code-for-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

So it seems like you only wanted to use the JavaScript as a fallback since you couldn't get the CSS to work. I would recommend against this as you may run into various compatibility issues between browsers and browser versions if you're not using a Polyfill.

To do this in CSS, I would recommend creating a container for each work item. In my example, I created a `.item` class and used that to contain the image and text. Once that was created, we can now look for a `:hover` on each `.item` and use that to modify the elements inside of our `.item`.

Let me know if you need me to clarify any part of my explanation or if I misunderstood any parts of your question.

```css
.item {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.work_container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 1200px; Removed for testing */
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.work_title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; /* Changed for testing */
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black; /* Changed for testing */
  
  /* Used for the animation */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.work-hub {
  width: 100%; /* Added for testing */
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 36px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
}

/* Run the hover on the container */
.item:hover .work_title {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="work_container">
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="work_title">Logo Visualisation</h1>
        <img class="work-hub" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg" alt="Work Image">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="work_title">Rock Banner</h1>
        <img class="work-hub" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg" alt="Work Image">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="work_title">Forest Fire</h1>
        <img class="work-hub" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg" alt="Work Image">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h1 class="work_title">Beach Body</h1>
        <img class="work-hub" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51IwmuOPQyL._SL1052_.jpg" alt="Work Image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```