# How to change css of image when other element is hovered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am making something where you can play html games on it. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="pong.html" id="togame">
    <img src="pong.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%; border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0; height: 130px;" id="gimg">
    <div class="container">
      <h4 style="font-size: x-large; padding: 0%;">Pong</h4>
      <p>Recreated version of retro game "pong", or table tennis on computer</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

can you make it so when i hover ona card anywhere, the images border-radius is changed? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'hover' in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css)

Comment: You cannot with inline styles, you need a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of inline styling, since it overrides anything that we declare in CSS.
So, I assigned a `.rounded` class in `<img>` tag. Then, you grab the parent element, which is `.card`, and you assign a hover rule on it. Then, you use the previously mentioned new class `.rounded` along with the change.
So you have something like this:

```css
.rounded {
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}

.card:hover .rounded {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.card {
  background: #ccc3;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="pong.html" id="togame">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" class="rounded" style="width:100%; height: 130px;" id="gimg">
    <div class="container">
      <h4 style="font-size: x-large; padding: 0%;">Pong</h4>
      <p>Recreated version of retro game "pong", or table tennis on computer</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Add a class to your `<img>` tag as I did like `class="imgHover"`
2. Create a CSS file and add the following line :

   .card:hover .imgHover { border-radius : 10px 10px 0 0 }
3. Modify the `border-radius` values as you wish

```css
.card:hover .imgHover { border-radius : 10px 10px 0 0 }

.imgHover {
 width:100%;
 height: 130px
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="pong.html" id="togame">
    <img class="imgHover" src="pong.png" alt="Avatar" id="gimg">
    <div class="container">
      <h4 style="font-size: x-large; padding: 0%;">Pong</h4> 
      <p>Recreated version of retro game "pong", or table tennis on computer</p> 
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```